# Call to undefined function storeExcelView() usando Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, funções, microsoft-excel

Tenho o seguinte problema, estou recebendo esta mensagem:

> Call to undefined function App\Jobs\Pit\Relatorios\Placar\storeExcelView()

Detalhe: estou usando PHP 7.2 e Laravel 6. O mesmo código no PHP 5.6 e Laravel 5.5 funcionam normalmente, poderiam me auxiliar?

**Código do Controller**

```php
$rota = 'administrativo.pit.relatorio.atividades.excel.placar_horas';
storeExcelView($dados, 'datas', $this->user, $name, $rota);
```

**Código do Helpers/Excel**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\Excel\CollectionExport;
use App\Exports\Excel\ViewExport;

function storeExcelView($datas, $name, $user, $nameExcel, $rota){

    $nomenclatura = $user->cod_usuario.''.date("Ymdhms").'-'.$nameExcel.'.xlsx';

    Excel::store(new ViewExport($rota, [$name => $datas]), $nomenclatura, 's3');

    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($nomenclatura, now()->addDay());   
    $data = array('title' => "Gerador de arquivos do E-Metodo",
                   'name' => $nameExcel,
                    'url' => $url);

    Mail::send('administrativo.mails.exports.arquivos.email', $data, function($message) use($user){
        $message->to($user->dsc_email, 'E-mail')
        ->subject('Gerador de arquivos')
        ->from('nao-responder-@ti.br', 'TI');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir resolver atualizei algumas bibliotecas do autoload inserindo as no files do Composer e depois rodei o comando 'composer dump-autoload -o' aí as dependências foram atualizadas para o php 7.2 e funcionou corretamente

"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/MenuHelper.php",
            "app/Helpers/DatasHelper.php",
            "app/Helpers/Exports/Excel.php"
        ]
    },